# Toasting SMS in flutter

Tags: flutter, sms, toast

I'm creating an app in flutter that toast the sms whenever a sms received on the mobile. I have no idea how to do this. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that Stack Overflow is neither a free code writing service nor a free tutorial provider. Askers are expected to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this. I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In flutter, if you want to achieve this kind of functionality than you need to use this plugin.

[https://pub.dev/packages/sms][1]

in this, you need to listen to on SMS received,

and message you will receive like this
need to add this in the main function

> `SmsReceiver receiver = new SmsReceiver(); receiver.onSmsReceived.listen((SmsMessage msg) => print(msg.body)); }`

But please make note that it will only work when your app is in foreground or background, if its destroy then it not be work

Comment: It should be done on runtime, mean as app is running and a message received it toast the body of the message. Can you write some code for it?

Comment: Is it for otp fatch?

Comment: No, not for OTP fetch. Just got a task to show the message body in Toast.

Comment: Yes for that you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/sms

Comment: I used this but I don't know how to get message and toast it as I receive it

Comment: I'm beginner, can you write a code for me to do this

Comment: @ZuHaib Hi! Unfortunately, Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service. Please refer to the links i shared on the comment above for more guidance. Goodluck :D